# How can I use dcast based on multiple columns?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, data-wrangling, dcast

I have data on this form in a data.table DT:

```
DT = data.table(
 year=c('1981', '1981', '1981', '2005', '2005', '2005'),
    value=c(2, 8, 16, 3, 9, 27),
    order =c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

| year | value | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '1981' | 2 | 1 |
| '1981' | 8 | 2 |
| '1981' | 16 | 3 |
| '2005' | 3 | 1 |
| '2005' | 9 | 2 |
| '2005' | 27 | 3 |

And I want to create new columns based first on the order within a specific year, but then sequentially on the order if I shift it. As you can see value=16 which starts as order=3 on row 1, is logged as order = 2 on row 2, etc.

| year | order1 | order2 | order3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '1981' | 2 | 8 | 16 |
| '1981' | 8 | 16 | NA |
| '1981' | 16 | NA | NA |
| '2005' | 3 | 9 | 27 |
| '2005' | 9 | 27 | NA |
| '2005' | 27 | NA | NA |

If I wanted it just by order, and get rows 1 and 4 as output, I could do:

```
dcast(DT, year ~ order, value.var = c('value'))
```

But how can I cast based on order while incorporating this reordering?

I could perhaps create new columns indicating the new shifted order, using:

```
DT[,order_2:= c(NA,1,2,NA,1,2)]
DT[,order_3:= c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1)]
```

But then how do I do casting on all three columns?
Is there a more elegant way than just casting 3 times and then joining the results?

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need `dcast`, try this:

```
DT[, lapply(seq_along(value), \(v) {l <- length(value); `length<-`(value[v:l], l)}), by=year]
#    year V1 V2 V3
# 1: 1981  2  8 16
# 2: 1981  8 16 NA
# 3: 1981 16 NA NA
# 4: 2005  3  9 27
# 5: 2005  9 27 NA
# 6: 2005 27 NA NA
```

Comment: nice concise solution : upvoted ;-). However, for a general solution perhaps first need to make sure DT is ordered by `year,order` (which happens to be the case here)

Comment: Great, this seems to work for the base case where I have the same number of columns for each group, but not for cases with fewer ordered observations. What is the meaning of the \(),  `length<-` and {} here?

Comment: @Hal You probably wonder about the `\(v)`, in new R versions its shorthand for `function(v)`, change this or better update your R. The others are all functions and documented: `?\`length<-\``,  `?\`{\``.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `shift` with `transpose`

```
library(data.table)
DT[, setNames(transpose(shift(value, n = seq_len(.N)-1, type = "lead")), 
      paste0("order", order)), year]
```

-output

```
   year order1 order2 order3
1: 1981      2      8     16
2: 1981      8     16     NA
3: 1981     16     NA     NA
4: 2005      3      9     27
5: 2005      9     27     NA
6: 2005     27     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dcast`, a little bit of other work to get it right:

```r
library(data.table)
dcast(year + order ~ paste0("order", ord2),
      data = DT[DT, on = .(year == year, order <= order)][, ord2 := seq(.N), by = .(year, order)],
      value.var = "i.value"
      )[, order := NULL
       ][, lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = patterns("^order"), by = .(year)][]
dcast(year + order ~ paste0("order", ord2), data = DT[DT, on = .(year == year, order <= order)][, ord2 := seq(.N), by = .(year, order)], value.var = "i.value")[, order := NULL][, lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = patterns("^order"), by = .(year)][]
#      year order1 order2 order3
#    <char>  <num>  <num>  <num>
# 1:   1981      2      8     16
# 2:   1981      8     16     NA
# 3:   1981     16     NA     NA
# 4:   2005      3      9     27
# 5:   2005      9     27     NA
# 6:   2005     27     NA     NA
```

Caveat: with *this* sample data, it is *significantly* slower than the other two answers. It is offered primarily to show that while it may be possible, it is not always the most efficient path:

```r
bench::mark(
  jay.sf  = DT[, lapply(seq_along(value), \(v) {l <- length(value); `length<-`(value[v:l], l)}), by=year],
  akrun   = DT[, setNames(transpose(shift(value, n = seq_len(.N)-1, type = "lead")), paste0("order", order)), year],
  r2evans = dcast(year + order ~ paste0("order", ord2), data = DT[DT, on = .(year == year, order <= order)][, ord2 := seq(.N), by = .(year, order)], value.var = "i.value")[, order := NULL][, lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = patterns("^order"), by = .(year)][],
  check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory              time               gc                  
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>              <list>             <list>              
# 1 jay.sf      225.2us 266.15us     3642.    48.6KB     5.38  1354     2      372ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [11 x 3]> <bench_tm [1,356]> <tibble [1,356 x 3]>
# 2 akrun       262.9us  307.4us     3149.    48.6KB     2.41  1305     1      414ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [12 x 3]> <bench_tm [1,306]> <tibble [1,306 x 3]>
# 3 r2evans      2.74ms   2.99ms      330.   453.3KB     2.30   143     1      434ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [91 x 3]> <bench_tm [144]>   <tibble [144 x 3]>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `shift(value, 0:-2)` makes this a one liner:

```
setnames(DT[, shift(value,(-0:-2)),year], c("year", paste0("order",1:3)))[]
```

Output:

```
   year order1 order2 order3
1: 1981      2      8     16
2: 1981      8     16     NA
3: 1981     16     NA     NA
4: 2005      3      9     27
5: 2005      9     27     NA
6: 2005     27     NA     NA
```